# Including manpages in Sphinx-generated documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx, manpage, troff

I'd like to include a unix manpage written in the traditional troff format in some Sphix-generated docs.

Is there any troff-to-rst converter?

The only solution I can think of is to convert the manpage directly to html with man2html.

Answer (score 0):

[pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) may be able to do what you want.